# Spring Roo 1.2.4: Roo_DataOnDemand aspect don't populate reference entities

Tags: java, spring, spring-roo

I have created a couple of entities with tests, using the roo shell:

```
roo> entity jpa --class ~.model.Entity1 --testAutomatically --activeRecord
roo> entity jpa --class ~.model.Entity2 --testAutomatically --activeRecord
...
roo> entity jpa --class ~.model.EntityN --testAutomatically --activeRecord
```

Then, I've started creating a relationships between them inside my IDE (IntelliJ idea), using JPA annotations (@NotNull @OneToOne, @OneToMany, etc). During this process, I kept running my integration tests, verifying the database architecture. Suddenly, one of my test failed with java.lang.NullPointerException. I've figured out, that somehow roo have changed the previously generated Roo_DataOnDemand aspect, so all the referenced entities became "null"-initized.

I can do the Push-In refactoring and initialize all the referencing entities by hand, but this is too slow. What have happened with roo aspect generator? How can I fix this, so that roo generator initialize all the references correctly?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like Roo have a problems with "grouping import statements", like:

```
import javax.persistence.*
```

In order to fix the problem, just expand the asterisks inside your entities. Example follows.

"Buggy" entity:

```
...
import javax.persistence.*;
...


@RooJavaBean
@RooToString
@RooJpaActiveRecord
@RooEquals
@ValidAdvocateCount
public class Formation {

    @NotNull
    @ManyToOne
    private Acol registrationAcol;

    /**
     */
    @NotNull
    @OneToOne
    private Contacts contacts;

    /**
     */
    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "formation")
    private Set<Advocate> advocates = new HashSet<Advocate>();

}
```

Invalid auto-generated aspect for that entity (irrelevant details removed):

```
    privileged aspect FormationDataOnDemand_Roo_DataOnDemand {

        declare @type: FormationDataOnDemand: @Component;

        private List<Formation> FormationDataOnDemand.data;

        public Formation FormationDataOnDemand.getNewTransientFormation(int index) {
            Formation obj = new Formation();
            setContacts(obj, index);
            setForm(obj, index);
            setName(obj, index);
            setRate(obj, index);
            setRegistrationAcol(obj, index);
            setResume(obj, index);
            setReviewDate(obj, index);
            setViews(obj, index);
            return obj;
        }

        public void FormationDataOnDemand.setContacts(Formation obj, int index) {
            Contacts contacts = null;
            obj.setContacts(contacts);
        }

        public void FormationDataOnDemand.setRegistrationAcol(Formation obj, int index) {
            Acol registrationAcol = null;
            obj.setRegistrationAcol(registrationAcol);
        }

    }
```

Fixed entity import example:

```
import javax.persistence.EnumType;
import javax.persistence.Enumerated;
import javax.persistence.Temporal;
import javax.persistence.TemporalType;
import javax.persistence.OneToOne;
import javax.persistence.OneToMany;
import javax.persistence.ManyToOne;
import javax.persistence.CascadeType;
import javax.validation.constraints.NotNull;
```

And here is a valid auto-generated aspect, after the fix:

```
 privileged aspect FormationDataOnDemand_Roo_DataOnDemand {

        declare @type: FormationDataOnDemand: @Component;

        private List<Formation> FormationDataOnDemand.data;

        @Autowired
        ContactsDataOnDemand FormationDataOnDemand.contactsDataOnDemand;

        @Autowired
        AcolDataOnDemand FormationDataOnDemand.acolDataOnDemand;

        public Formation FormationDataOnDemand.getNewTransientFormation(int index) {
            Formation obj = new Formation();
            setContacts(obj, index);
            setForm(obj, index);
            setName(obj, index);
            setRate(obj, index);
            setRegistrationAcol(obj, index);
            setResume(obj, index);
            setReviewDate(obj, index);
            setViews(obj, index);
            return obj;
        }

        public void FormationDataOnDemand.setContacts(Formation obj, int index) {
            Contacts contacts = contactsDataOnDemand.getSpecificContacts(index);
            obj.setContacts(contacts);
        }

        public void FormationDataOnDemand.setRegistrationAcol(Formation obj, int index) {
            Acol registrationAcol = acolDataOnDemand.getRandomAcol();
            obj.setRegistrationAcol(registrationAcol);
        }

    }
```